# Symfony multiple access_denied_url

Tags: routes, symfony

I am trying to restrict access to certain routes using the Symfony framework.
Currently I have the following in my `security.yml` file:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/my/account, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/my, roles: ROLE_ACTIVE }
```

When a user is not logged in and tries to access one of the account pages `^/my` then they are redirected to the login page - this is correct.

When a user is logged in and tries to access one of the account pages, but their account is not activated (i.e. they don't have role `ROLE_ACTIVE`), then they are redirected to the activation page - this is correct.
I found the following achieves this:

```
firewalls:
    default:
        ...
        access_denied_url: activate
```

However, now because of the `access_denied_url: activate` when a logged in user tries to access `^/admin` and they are not admin (i.e. they don't have role `ROLE_ADMIN`) they are redirected to the `activate` page. Instead I want to redirect them to the `my_homepage` page. How can I achieve this?

Alternatively, I would settle for being able to display the not authorised page, but if I add the `@Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")` to my admin controller and remove the `{ path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }` from `access_control` it does the same thing - i.e. redirects to the activate page.

Whole `security.yml` file for reference:

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\Account:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:Account

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        admin:
            pattern: ^/admin
            access_denied_url: my_homepage
            anonymous: ~
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /            
            provider: our_db_provider

            simple_form:
                authenticator: login_authenticator
                check_path:    login
                login_path:    my_homepage

        default:
            anonymous: ~
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%secret%'
                # Expire in 30 days
                lifetime: 2592000 
                path:     /
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /            
            provider: our_db_provider

            simple_form:
                authenticator: login_authenticator
                check_path:    login
                login_path:    login

            access_denied_url: activate

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/my/account, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/my, roles: ROLE_ACTIVE }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a specific firewall for urls matching with `^/admin` pattern:

```
admin:
    pattern:  ^/admin
    access_denied_url: my_homepage
    # ...
```

**EDIT**

You need to share the same `context` between your two firewalls:

```
admin:
    pattern: ^/admin
    context: default
    access_denied_url: my_homepage
    anonymous: ~
    logout:
        path:   /logout
        target: /            
    provider: our_db_provider

    simple_form:
        authenticator: login_authenticator
        check_path:    login
        login_path:    login
```

Note that I changed the `login_path` same as the `default` firewall.

And add the same line to the `default`:

```
default:
    anonymous: ~
    context: default
    remember_me:
        secret:   '%secret%'
        # Expire in 30 days
        lifetime: 2592000 
        path:     /
    logout:
        path:   /logout
        target: /            
    provider: our_db_provider

    simple_form:
        authenticator: login_authenticator
        check_path:    login
        login_path:    login

    access_denied_url: activate
```

Replace your firewalls by those ones and it should works as expected.

[Read more about contexts here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context)

Comment: I tried that but I get an error: `InvalidConfigurationException in SecurityExtension.php line 435: No authentication listener registered for firewall "admin".`

Comment: You need to add configuration in the same way as your `default` firewall (i.e. `login_form` & other mandatory parameters) . I don't have the configuration of the `default` firewall, also I cannot reproduce it for you. Just copy the first and change the `pattern` and the `access_denied_url`

Comment: I thought that, so I added the exact same as default (except for access_denied_url is different obviously) but instead of redirecting to the activate route it redirects to login.

Comment: Which role have the user that you uses to access the route ? If he is not authenticated, it's the expected behavior. Otherwise, trick by changing the `login_path` to `my_homepage` .

Comment: **Changing `login_path` to `my_homepage` worked. Thanks.** I thought I had tried that before but it threw an error. Strange. The user I'm testing with is logged in but just doesn't have the `ROLE_ADMIN` role, as I'm testing to make sure non-admin users can't access the admin area and get redirected to the main users home page. Not sure why the default behaviour is to redirect to login though as they are logged in, just not authorised with the correct role.

Comment: It's strange that you can be redirected to the `my_homepage` route using the `login_path`, but be redirected to login if you use `my_homepage` as `access_denied_url` . I'll keep you informed if I found the reason.

Comment: **This solution has broken accessing the admin section**. Now it always redirects to `my_homepage`, even when an admin user tried to access it. With an admin logged in I took out the whole `admin` firewall and can access the admim section fine, but put it back and always redirected to `my_homepage`!

Comment: Can you add your `firewalls` and `access_control` to your question please ?

Comment: I've added the whole file to the question.

Comment: @CarlPorter see my edit. Say me if the original problem persists.

Comment: **Terrific - that solves the problem**. It does have one unwanted side-effect though. If a non-active user attempts to view `/admin` then they are redirected to - and can view - `my_homepage`. Where if they try and view it directly it redirects to `activate`. If I have to live with that it's fine, as most are unlikely to do this and it will only give them access to view that overview page (if they click any links they get redirected to `activate`).

Comment: You can add an entry in `access_control` with a path that matches your `my_homepage` and restrict it to specific roles , e.g. `- { path: ^/route/to/homepage, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ACTIVATE] }` . Thanks for the vote =)

Comment: I already have one as `my_homepage` is just `/my`. `{ path: ^/my, roles: ROLE_ACTIVE }`

Comment: Very strange. Maybe the `@Security("has_role('ROLE_ACTIVE')")` can do the job ?

Comment: No. I'm guessing that creates an infinite loop as it crashes my apache server! I think I will just change the redirect to a non-secure page (the main homepage), which will resolve the problem anyway. Thanks again.